# Expose new ART functionality by changing the Runtime.class of libcore

Tags: java, android, c++, android-source, android-runtime

I have inserted some new functionality in the Android Runtime ([ART](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/)), and now I want to expose it to the outside world via an interface. As it is native code, I will be using the `JNI` interface to call this new functionality, in a similar way with the Garbage Collector functionality: `Runtime.getInstance().gc()`.

However, I don't care in building a new SDK that could be used by an IDE, as I will be manually injecting bytecode to .dex files that will make the call.

I have edited the `Runtime.java` in `libcore/luni`, and `java_lang_Runtime.cc` in `art` in a similar way with the `gc()` function. I am generating the new `libart.so` and `core-libart.jar` and I flash them on a device.
However, when I try to reboot the device, I get the message:

```
Failed to register native method java.lang.Runtime.myMethod()V in /system/framework/core-libart.jar
...
----- class 'Ljava/lang/Runtime;' cl=0x0 -----
vtable (24 entries, 11 in super):
// 24 entries are listed here. My entry is missing.
...
```

In the `Runtime.java` I register the native method and supress some warnings on a full build using @hide. eg,

```
/** @hide */
public native void myMethod();
```

In the `java_lang_Runtime.cc`, I define the function (that will call the ART internal stuff) and register it to the gMethods[] array using a macro. eg,

```
static void Runtime_myMethod(JNIEnv*, jclass) {  
// body
}
```

`NATIVE_METHOD(Runtime, myMethod, "()V")`

The device is on a bootloop. Are there any other files that I should have edited? Should I build extra modules, or send any other files on the device?

BTW, I do NOT want to build a new `SDK` as for calling `myMethod` I will inject `Dalvik bytecode` to an APK file. Basically I will get the Runtime instance, and then call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**

Android ships the factory images with framework components being pre-optimised.
The file `boot.oat` contains pre-optimised code (or odex code), which can be accessed by reading pointers contained in the `boot.art` file.

These two files contain code only for the `boot classpath`.
The rest of the framework, and the rest of the system applications (in `app` and `priv-app`) folders have standalone `odex` files.

During this pre-optimisation phase, the dex code is **taken out** of a framework module (a jar, or an apk), is compiled using `dex2oat`, and the resulting code resides in the files I just mentioned.

**Some of the things I 've tried:**

Shipping just the `libart.so` and `core-libart.jar` does not work, even though the latter contains the dex code. This is because the runtime is still attempting to read that information from `boot.oat`.

By modifying the device configuration to do the pre-optimisation, the `aosp build system` can generate `boot.oat|art` and the rest of the `odex` files (more [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure.html)). I expected that flashing all these should work, but it didn't.
(at least for the `marshmallow-release` branch, on a nexus6)

I 've tried flashing the whole aosp-generated build, and it didn't work, even with a custom kernel that I 've build with the security features (`verity`) disabled.

I am sure that some of these should have worked, but there must be something else that should be considered during building the OS.

**Solution:**

The last resort, was `deodexing` and thankfully it worked.
I have written a small [script](https://github.com/Paschalis/android_scripts/tree/master/deodex) that does it for the Nexus 6 on Marshmallow.

The script, during a 1st stage, it takes out all the `oat/odex` code from relevant places, and de-optimises it to `dex` code, thanks to the [oat2dex](https://github.com/testwhat/SmaliEx) and [smali](https://bitbucket.org/JesusFreke/smali/) projects.
On a 2nd stage, it packs the `dex` code back, in the framework modules (jars/apks).

Shipping a whole new `core-libart.jar` to the device still does not work (not sure why), but tinkering the dex files before packing them into the modules does the trick! **:))**

The `libart.so` can now find `Runtime.myMethod()`, which can be invoked by an application (smali tinkering again) to run my code inside `ART`.